# Google's new reCaptcha doesn't work on Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone, recaptcha

The recaptcha box isn't displaying on WP8 with official IE mobile browser.

Just go with the device (I tried with wp8) to the official demo page:

http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo

and you will see that the recaptcha box isn't displaying.

Comment: I think there is a problem with the iframe google is trying to inject in the page... At the moment I have to fall back to the google's old captcha just for windows phone users. That's annoying. I did also open a ticket on the official recaptcha forum: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/recaptcha/l0-5DoINWYc

Comment: it's not working for the webbrowser control also :(
This is still not solved

Comment: Sorry @ClintonWard, what do you mean with "the webbrowser control" ?

Comment: Yes. I worked it out, If you have Visibility set to collapsed and back to visible, the captcha never loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved: I'm using a Windows Phone without a SIM card to develop with, but when I first configured the phone 1 year ago, I set to automatically synchronize date and time. (like everyone does)

However, without a SIM card and over WiFi, the phone doesn't sync the date and time, and therefore the https certificate from google appeared as expired and the iframe didn't load.

Adjusting the date and the time manually solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It should be fixed for now. But if the issue still persists for your service, try to fall back to alternative challenge, as described [here](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#no_checkbox), when the user agent  string contains **IEMobile** word.
See related topic at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/recaptcha/2ITB1n8D2II for details.

Comment: It's not a problem with the UA, and the fallback isn't working on IEMobile at the moment.